# PC3200 vs PC5300 RAM Spec

Tags: memory

Micron recommend [UDIMM memory](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/pavilion-a1330n-series/CT509296) for a [HP Pavilion 1330](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/HP-Compaq/pavilion-a1330n-series)

DDR PC3200 • CL=3 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • DDR400 • 2.6V • 128Meg x 64

Can I expect [DDR PC5300](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009W9TAG) to work properly in the device?  Is the difference between PC3200 vs PC5300 due to limits for clocking the RAM?

Comment: That computer is 10+ years old in 2016. Don't even try to upgrade - just buy a new PC.

Comment: @TurboJ  At $60 for 2GB I agree.  I have a hunch: it is possible to find 2GB for $10 on AMZN: http://superuser.com/questions/1140003/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the difference between PC3200 vs PC5300 due to limits for clocking the RAM?

Worse: The voltage *and* the pinout is different. The PC5300 modules literally do not fit into DDR-1 PC3200 slots.

On [HP](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00572524) web page:  `Type: 184 pin, DDR SDRAM`

On [Amazon DDR-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009W9TAG): `Form Factor: 240-pin DIMM`