# Process to determine RAM compatibility

Tags: memory

Crucial.com has a database to identify the correct RAM for a PC.  It  indicted my project PC uses  RAM specs:

http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/pavilion-a1330n-series/CT509296

At these prices, I would be better off buying a new computer for my nephew.  That being said, If I could purchase 2GB for ~$10 then this would be economically viable.  That being said this computer will be dedicated as an Ubuntu box for a nephew to gain Unix exposure

The crucial.com RAM Specs include:

```
DDR PC3200 • 
CL=3 • 
Unbuffered • 
NON-ECC •
DDR400 • 
2.6V • 
128Meg x 64
```

Which of these specs must be explicitly matched with the candidates below to ensure compatibility?

I fed the keywords

```
ddr400 pc3200
```

into Amazon.com and it returned:

[https://www.amazon.com/DESKTOP-Modules-184-pin-Genuine-Tech/dp/B00C53GZ68](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C53GZ68)

[https://www.amazon.com/Crucial-PC3200-UNBUFFERED-NON-ECC-184-PIN/dp/B0009PAYY8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009PAYY8)

I’d like to ensure that I order an equivalent part.  It will require the same physical form factor (184 Pin DIMM).    Before ordering these parts, I would appreciate any guidance to avoid ordering incompatible RAM.  Thank you for your assistance.

*If you feel this question is deficient in any way, please consider either asking a question or editing it before either downvoting or putting it on hold.*

Comment: Generally speaking, you need RAM modules of the identical type (DDR), same or faster speed (PC3200 or faster), and identical error correcting type (Non-ECC).  But this is only a general rule. Some systems won't work unless all modules are identical speed and in some cases even the same organization (128Mx64).  Bottom line, your best bet is to order RAM with identical specs to what you already have, or be prepared to do trial and error if you order modules that differ even slightly.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes... OP isn't asking for a recommendation, has explained his/her research and where the confusion is.

Comment: @Dave I am puzzled by this response as well.  Some stackexchange communities are extremely quick to pull the trigger and shoot a question without truly reading and understanding the OP intent.  When they see a link to a product, they automatically assume it is for a product recommendation.   This is a flaw in the culture that stackexchange would do well to influence a change in culture

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old computer to be upgrading.

That said, your computer handles sticks up to 1GB in size of the DDR spec (not DDR2, DDR3, etc, just DDR). DDR400 is the speed, as is PC3200. They are two ways of saying the same thing.

The OEM website notes the computer can handle a maximum of 4GB of DDR memory, in 4x1GB stick configuration: http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c00572524

OPINION: *In my experience though, plugging new hardware into a computer of this age has a very high chance of introducing or revealing faults that could be fatal to the computer. If you can find someone getting rid of a computer with the same memory, I'd grab the memory sticks and use them, but I would not pay for memory to upgrade this computer.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a challenging task. It depends on what kind of NorthBridge is used in the a1330 PC, and how it is routed to DIMM slots on a particular mainboard. At that time there was a distinction between "low density" DIMMs versus "high-density" DIMMs, all related to memory chip organisation, something related to either chip select or number of address lines per chip. The 1GB DIMM can be two-sided (I believe it is with "low density"), or one-sided, which may (or may not) work. 128M x64 seems to imply a 8-chip DIMM, but again, there were DDR DIMMs with 4 chips per side. Go to e-Bay for cheapest DIMMs, buy 2 pieces, try, and then buy two more from the same place. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If desktop DDR, then yes, but any DDR DIMM will work (doesn't need to be 400MHz/PC-3200). This is old RAM and not much is made anymore so supply and demand may make it cheaper to get a slightly different specification. Also with DDR, 1GB is the maximum size on a single 184pin module.

Just don't get DDR2, DDR3 or DDR4 as they are different. If it's a notebook it is probably be a SO-DIMM module instead of a DIMM module the rest applies the same.